# Let $S^1=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ be the unit circle. Prove that $G:[0,1)\to S^1$, $G(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$ is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $S^1=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ be the unit circle with the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $G:[0,1)\to S^1$, $G(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$ is not a homeomorphism

I think $G^{-1}(x,y)$ will not be continuous but I'm not sure how to prove this.

I believe the issue is that $[0,a)$ is open in the subspace topology on $[0,1)$ but because a circle is a loop the image will never be open in the circle? So the inverse won't be continuous as the preimage of this open set, will not be open in the circle.

I'm not sure how to compute the inverse of this map however, so I'm not sure how I could show that this won't be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Homeomorphisms are open maps, so must take the open set $[0,.5)$ to an open set.

Comment: An intuitive way to see this, is to look at the "zero" of the circle. Whatever the inverse might be, a neighborhood of zero would need to be  close to 0 and 1 and the same time.

Comment: The simpliest (in my opinion) is: $S^1$ is compact, while $[0,1)$ not, continuous function should map compact set to compact, hence $G^{-1}$ cannot be continuous. To see why $[0,1)$ isn't compact, just take sequence $x_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to going about it: show that $[0,1)$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic  is the first. If you’ve covered compactness you can say $S^1$ is compact and the first space is not ( not closed in $\Bbb R$ or give a cover etc. ) or if you’ve covered connectedness you can say that we can remove *any* point of the circle and are left with a connected set, while for $[0,1)$ we can only remove $0$ to have that property. Etc.

You can also directly show that $G^{-1}$ is not continuous. It’s not really needed to give a formula, just look at how $G$ works: a number $0 \le t < 1$ is scaled to an angle $0 \le 2\pi$ (in radians) and sent to the unique point in the complex plane of radius $1$ and argument (angle with the positive real axis) equal to that angle. So the inverse for a point on $S^1$ we can compute by taking the argument, which lies in $[0,2\pi)$ and scaling it back to $[0,1)$. Now look at the sequence on the circle that converges to $(1,0)$ coming from below the positive real axis. So $(x_n,y_n)= (\cos(2\pi(-\frac1n)),\sin(2\pi(-\frac1n))$, which has argument $2\pi ( 1-\frac1n)$ so $G^{-1}(x_n,y_n)=1-\frac1n \not \to 0=G^{-1}(1,0)$. So $G^{-1}$ is not sequentially continuous.

Comment: Could I show that given an epsilon ball around $(1,0)$ there will be a point $(\cos(2\pi (1-\delta)),\sin(2\pi(1-\delta)))$ which is in that ball but not in $[0,\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: @AColoredReptile that follows from the existence of my sequence. It will also work.

Comment: I figured it would follow from the component functions being continuous. I haven't heard of sequential continuous before.

Comment: @AColoredReptile it’s the same continuity in metric spaces. The component functions argument shows that $G$ is continuous but doesn’t apply to the inverse.

Comment: But could I show that $G$ is not an open map, which would imply its inverse is not continuous?

Comment: @AColoredReptile sure, $O=[0,\frac12)$ is open in $[0,1)$ but its image in $S^1$ is not. It’s all the same argument in variants.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the comments is the way to go. But if you want to show directly that 
$G^{-1}$ is not continuous, note that

$(\cos 2\pi/n,\sin 2\pi/n)\to (1,0)$ and $G^{-1}(\cos 2\pi/n,\cos 2\pi/n)\to 0$

whereas

$(\cos (2\pi(1-1/n)),\sin (2\pi(1-1/n)))\to (1,0)$ and $G^{-1}(\cos (2\pi(1-1/n)),\sin (2\pi(1-1/n)))\to 1$